# How can I get data from multiple mysql tables and store in user session?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables: USER and ROSTER. Previously, I've been able to query and retrieve the proper student and direct the user to the proper page. Moving forward, I'd like to query the tables and retrieve the users studentID, name, period, and access.

**USER**

studentID
name
access

**ROSTER**
    id
    period

```
    $studentID = $_POST['studentID'];

    $studentID = stripslashes($studentID);

    $studentID = mysql_real_escape_string($studentID);
    $getUser_sql = "SELECT * FROM USER, ROSTER WHERE USER.studentID='$studentID'";
    $getUser = mysql_query($getUser_sql);

    $getUser_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUser);

    $getUser_RecordCount = mysql_num_rows($getUser);

    if($getUser_RecordCount==1){



       session_start();
       $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
       $_SESSION['studentID'] = $studentID;


    header("location:login_success.php");

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at examples @[tizag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php) and @[mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-tables.html), but I just can't get this going.

Comment: Try joining the tables then pull from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing a proper JOIN, so I am assuming the join is 1 to 1:

```
SELECT studentID, name, access, period 
FROM USER JOIN ROSTER ON user.studentid = roster.id 
WHERE USER.studentID = '$studentID'
```

The 'ON' is the important part as it defines WHAT to join ON, the WHERE in this SQL is a filter of the OVERALL data.

Comment: a join can however also be written "implicitly", without the JOIN keyword: `"SELECT * 
FROM USER, ROSTER WHERE user.studentid = roster.id AND USER.studentID='$studentID'"`; but I agree, the join condition is missing

Comment: @nyarlathotep, I like to just keep it clean and easy to read, the JOIN .. ON helps me do that.

Comment: that's fine with me, just wanted to point out that the syntax OP has is actually not so far from what he needs; it is an interesting question (although probably more one of taste) which syntax is better (readable or whatever). I usually use the JOIN syntax as well, but in some cases I find it nicer to have a list of all tables participating in the query in one place :D

Comment: Question answered! Thanks so much for the quick response @Jakub. Now I see how to use JOIN and hopefully won't make that mistake again.